# Multiple Timers Arduino

Tags: c, timer, arduino

Hi I had a question about timers on that Arduino.

I have 5 physical buttons (piezos) that I am getting the analog input from. I am then having them write out a keyboard key. My issue is when one is hit I want it to be unable to hit for "x" amount of time. I tried using delay, but this ended up delaying the whole program, thus 2 buttons could not be hit at the same time. Could someone explain to me how to do this with timers? I want 5 separate timers 1 for each button that controls a Boolean, I would need 5 separate timers for 5 separate if statements. (See code).

```
//SNARE LOOP2  
if(sensorValueA0 == 0)
{
  if(SnareHit == false)
  {

  Keyboard.write(115);
  SnareHit = true;
  //Use timer here to delay this part of the system
  SnareHit = false;
  }
}
//BASS DRUM LOOP
if(sensorValueA1 == 0)
{
  if(BassHit == false)
  {

  Keyboard.write(98);
  BassHit = true;
  //Use timer here to delay this part of the system
  BassHit = false;
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the millis() function, something similar to the following code:

```
if(ButtonPress==true){
 time=millis() //time was previously declared as unsigned long
    if(time>=5000){ //5000 = 5 sec
     ButtonPress==false
    }
}
```

It will not stop the arduino loop as dealy() does.
More info: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvoidDelay

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to de-bounce the button. I usually do this in the main loop, and expect 5 consecutive "pressed" reads before I say the button is really pressed, something like this:

```
int  button1PressedCount = 0;
int  debounceCounter = 5; // Number of successive reads before we say the switch is pressed
boolean buttonPressed = false;
int inputPin1 = 7;

void setup() {
  // Grounding the input pin causes it to actuate
  pinMode(inputPin1, INPUT ); // set the input pin 1
  digitalWrite(inputPin1, HIGH); // set pin 1 as a pull up resistor.
}

void loop()     
{
  // Some code

  // Check button, we evaluate below
  checkButton();

  // Some more code
}

void checkButton() {
  if (digitalRead(inputPin) == 0) {
    // We need consecutive pressed counts to treat this is pressed    
    if (button1PressedCount < debounceCounter) {
      button1PressedCount += 1;
      // If we reach the debounce point, mark the start time
      if (button1PressedCount == debounceCounter) {
        // Button is detected as pressed!
        buttonPressed = true;
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (button1PressedCount == debounceCounter) {
        // We were pressed, but are not any more 
        buttonPressed = false;
    }

    button1PressedCount = 0;
  }
}
```

Also it seems using an analogue input with a check if the analogue value is exactly equal to 0 might be a bit sensitive in noisy environments. This is why I use a digital input and the internal pull up resistor.